# If a set $S$ contains $n$ natural numbers. Then there exists a nonempty subset of $S$ sum of whose elements is divisible by n.

Tags: number-theory

If one of the elements of the set $S$ be divisible by $n$ or each element of $S$ belongs to the same residue class then our result is obvious.So, we have to prove it for the case where neither any element is divisible by $n$ nor they belong to the same residue class.Let $S=\{a_i; i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and let $k_i$ be the remainder when $a_i$ is divided by $n$,for $i=1,2,...,n$. Now we just need to show there exist $r\leq n$-$k_i$'s such that sum of $r$-$k_i$'s is divisible by $n$. But inspite of my repeated efforts I fail to do this. Please help me for proving this case.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $S_1=a_1$, $S_2=a_1+a_2$,..., $S_n=a_1+a_2+...+a_n$, where $S=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$. So if none of the $S_i$ is divisible by $n$, then there are $i\lt j$ such that $S_i\equiv S_j$ (mod. $n$). So $S_j-S_i=a_{i+1}+...+a_j$ is divisible by $n$. Then $A=\{a_{i+1},...,a_j\}$ has the property.

Comment: What is the way for finding Sj for each Si, which is not a divisor of n.

Comment: If $S_i$ is not divisible by $n$ for every $1\leq i\leq n$ so we have that by Pingehole principle that two, say, $S_i$ and $S_j$ have the same resudue modulus $n$.